# Why does my image's quality go down when saving PPT to PDF?

Tags: pdf, images, microsoft-powerpoint, compression, pptp

In power point 2013, on the first slide I have this picture in PNG
[image]

Aftering saving the PPT to PDF it becomes
[image]

As you can see the image has became blurry around the edges of the letters.

Now this is after I went into Options -> Advanced -> Do not compress image

[image]

Why does my picture become blurry? Is there anyway to preserve the quality of this picture?

Comment: I can't recreate that scenario. Even with the setting unticked, the PDF has a crisp image.

Comment: Do you have the zillion patches and service packs applied to your office 2013 version?

Comment: a) Did you choose "Do not compress images ..." before inserting the image and saving the file or did you choose it later?  If the latter, too late.  Set it first before adding any images.  b) did you insert the image on a slide that includes a picture or content placeholder and did the picture drop into the placeholder?  If so, PPT has compressed the image REGARDLESS of your settings.  It's a bug.  Try inserting the same image onto a blank slide AFTER setting the compression option.  Then make PDF and choose the Standard Publishing option in the PDF save dialog box.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Thanks, I found a workaround this problem. I first saved the PPT as a EMF file, this is a high quality picture. Then opening up this EMF file in paint, I printed via a PDF printer. This produces the highquality rendering I needed. This is pretty work intensive but I need this in a hurry. I will try what you said now to see if there is any difference.

Comment: Hurry.  Understood.  But please do let us know what you find out once the crisis is past.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me is

1. Print the file to A3 format [good resolution, but wrong dimensions]
2. Open the .pdf file with a pdf editor (e.g. Photoshop) and save in correct dimensions. [usually widescreen, e.g. some multiple of 1920x1080]

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot you showed us says 220 dpi.

The pdf converter that Microsoft provides for Microsoft Word is awful if you're printing professionally because it compresses images. For printing to be efficient, all images in your document need to be 300 dpi and be a `.tiff` file type because other image file types (gif, png, jpeg) don't have support for dpi. and instead default to 72 or 80 dpi.

I recommend you download [DoPDF](http://dopdf.com). It's free. If you have problems with using 300 dpi in version 11, try version 9.

Answer (score 0):

I want to put forth what ended up being the issue for me: When making a poster, my ppt slide size was some default size with a 16:9 aspect ratio. When converting to pdf, images degraded even with the advanced options to avoid compression and output high fidelity. Even an svg image degraded. What ended up being critical to the solution is ensuring that the slide size was a custom maximum size of 56 x 31.5. Once I changed that, the output pdf was beautiful. None of the MS forums I found mention this so I figured I'd post it somewhere in case it was relevant to someone.